# Is this a reasonable way to run sections of go code as root on Linux?

Tags: go

What is the best way to run sections of my go code as root on Linux? I am writing a sizable web app and do not want to run the whole app as root. Some of the code needs to manipulate the network stack, firewall rules, etc and therefore must run as root.

Currently, I have created a small stub executable that calls code back in my larger app. I then compile the stub and set the Linux suid bit. I then call it from my main go app as a shell command.

It works. But is this the most efficient way? Is there an idiomatic way?

Plan B was to use a REST API from a small HTTP service. Though that is a little harder to secure.

Thoughts?

e.g... the exec doupdate has the suid set for root permissions

From within the web app...

```
// Elevate UpdateNft to root
func ElevateUpdateNFT() string {
    out, err := exec.Command("doupdate", "nft").CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Print("exec doupdate ", err)
    }
    if len(out) > 0 {
        log.Print(string(out))
    }
    return string(out)
}
```

Inside doupdate, executing as root... CallUpdateNft is back in the main web app but now running with root permissions.

```
func main() {
...
    case key == "nft":
        models.CallUpdateNft()
...
}
```

Comment: I would probably use gRPC, or if you want the communication to be asynchronous, you could use events.

Comment: When you say "CallUpdateNft is back in the main web app", do you mean you are including the source from the main web app in this suid root app? Because you can't call functions across process boundaries. Executing a second binary works, but  a better way would be to run a server as root that opens a domain socket, and the other application connecting to it to issue commands. grpc, or any other rpc would work.

Comment: I had not thought of an rpc. I guess that would be a lot better than rest.

Comment: The second executable does work. It's a separate executable (with its own main) that calls the same utility packages as the main web app. So, from a programming point of view, it seems like just a stub to the same functions (with very little code of its own). But from a binary perspective, it's compiled entirely separately.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your approach but suid binaries [have a poor reputation...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Security)

---

Afaik there are at least three ways to do this.

1. start as root and drop privileges for parts that don't need root
2. allow some user to run a command as root with sudo
3. make a privileged process do something

#### One

This will run the web server without privileges.

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/webserver", "--foo", "--bar")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
            Credential: &syscall.Credential{
                Gid: uint32(33),
                Uid: uint32(33)}}
cmd.Start();
```

#### Two

/etc/sudoers.d/www-data :

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/webserver
```

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("sudo", "/bin/webserver", "--foo", "--bar")
cmd.Start();
```

#### Three

Communicate to a privileged process and make it do stuff.

```
$ go run both.go library.go  /etc/shadow
0
open /etc/shadow: permission denied
```

server as root:

```
$ make serve 
go build -o server server.go library.go ; sudo ./server
```

then connect:

```
$ ./client /etc/shadow  | wc -l
1918
ok.
69
```

##### Makefile

```golang
all: stop
    go build -o client client.go library.go
    go build -o server server.go library.go
    ./server & sleep 0.2
    ./client $(path)
both:
    go build -o sc both.go library.go && ./sc $(path)
stop: ; killall server || true
serve: ; go build -o server server.go library.go ; sudo ./server
clean: ; rm -vf client sc server
```

##### both.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go Server(wg, "")


    path := "main.go"
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        path = os.Args[1]
    }
    resp, err := Client(path)

    if nil == err {
        fmt.Print(resp.Output)
    } else {
        println(err.Error())
    }
    wg.Wait()

}
```

##### client.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    path := "/dev/null"
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        path = os.Args[1]
    }
    resp, err := Client(path)
    if nil == err {
        println("ok.")
        fmt.Print(resp.Output)
    } else {
        println(err.Error())
    }

}
```

##### library.go

```golang
package main

import (
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const Addr = "localhost:31337"

type Api struct {
    server *rpc.Server
    quit   *sync.WaitGroup
}

func newApi(address string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) (*Api, error) {
    if len(address) == 0 {
        address = Addr
    }
    rpcs := rpc.NewServer()
    errR := rpcs.RegisterName("V1", &MethodsV1{ Quit : wg })
    sock, errL := net.Listen("tcp", address)
    if errR != nil {
        return nil, errR
    }
    if errL != nil {
        return nil, errL
    }
    go rpcs.Accept(sock)
    return &Api{server: rpcs, quit: wg}, nil
}

func Server(wg *sync.WaitGroup, addr string) {
    _, err := newApi(addr, wg)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    if wg != nil {
        wg.Wait()
    } else {
        <- time.After(time.Second * 50)
    }
}

func Client(path string) (RpcResponse, error) {
    addr := Addr
    if a := os.Getenv("ADDR"); len(a) > 0 {
        addr = a
    }
    resp := RpcResponse{}
    client, errC := rpc.Dial("tcp", addr)
    if nil == errC {
        errC = client.Call("V1.Cat", &path, &resp);
        println(len(resp.Output))
    }
    return resp, errC
}

type RpcResponse struct { Output string }
type MethodsV1 struct {
    Quit *sync.WaitGroup
}

func (m1 *MethodsV1) Cat(path *string, response *RpcResponse) error {
    if m1.Quit != nil {
        defer m1.Quit.Done()
    }
    o, err := os.ReadFile(*path)
    response.Output = string(o)
    return err
}
```

##### server.go

```golang
package main

func main() {
    Server(nil, "")
}
```